# I want to find a number with some conditions

Tags: java, math

I have this problem in mind, and I think there is a solution, but im not finding one

```
a*x = z
b*y = t
a+b < z && a+b < t && z<=t
```

This is my code

```
public static double solveEquation(double a, double x, double y) {
    double z = a * x; // Calculate z
    System.out.println("z: " + z);
    double b = z / y - a; // Calculate b
    System.out.println("b: " + b);
    double t = b * y;  // Calculate t
    System.out.println("t: " + t);
    
    

    if (a + b < z && a + b < t && z <= t) {
        return b;
    }
    return Double.NaN; // Return NaN if no solution found
}
```

the best case was if I only give the 'x' and 'y' and then it will find me the 'a' and the 'b'

I tried the method above but I cant get the right result

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. The code you show only finds a `b` given `a`, `x`, and `y`. But then the text under talks about finding `a` and `b` from a pair `x` and `y`.

Comment: Can the values be negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, assuming the values `a`, `x` and `y` to be positive (and non-zero): -

Since `z <= t`, we technically only have to satisfy two conditions:

1. `z <= t` Which translates to `a * x <= b * y`
2. `a + b < z`

Due to positive numbers constraints, we can simplify the first one to:

`b >= (a * x) / y`

So, I think this code should do what you want:

```
public static double solveEquation(double a, double x, double y) {
    double z = a * x; // Calculate z
    System.out.println("z: " + z);
    double b = z / y; // Calculate b
    System.out.println("b: " + b);
    double t = b * y;  // Calculate t
    System.out.println("t: " + t);
    
    

    if (a + b < z && z <= t) {
        return b;
    }
    return Double.NaN; // Return NaN if no solution found
}
```